# Rolling correlation between zoo objects of unequal size

Tags: r

I have two zoo objects of unequal size (inflow and outflow).  Outflow values lag inflow by some unknown amount of time.  I would like to determine the correlation between the smaller outflow object (6 rows) and the larger inflow object (many rows), 6 rows at a time, starting at the inflow beginning time, incrementing by one, and find the  period of highest correlation.  I think this is called a "sliding window" comparison.  I've tried many different ways, unsuccessfully, to use the "rollapply" function to do this but get an error because the size difference between the two objects.  Hope someone will understand what I'm trying to ask and can offer a solution.  Below is a portion of my data and an example of how I have tried to use the rollapply function.

```
> inflow
(03/14/13 07:00:00) 11.20451
(03/14/13 07:02:00) 11.03810
(03/14/13 07:04:00) 11.03012
(03/14/13 07:06:00) 11.09517
(03/14/13 07:08:00) 10.90878
(03/14/13 07:10:00) 11.23285
(03/14/13 07:12:00) 11.14890
(03/14/13 07:14:00) 11.17002
(03/14/13 07:16:00) 11.38342
(03/14/13 07:18:00) 11.70833
(03/14/13 07:20:00) 11.93776
(03/14/13 07:22:00) 12.17832
(03/14/13 07:24:00) 12.39648
(03/14/13 07:26:00) 12.24020
(03/14/13 07:28:00) 12.18667
(03/14/13 07:30:00) 12.45410
(03/14/13 07:32:00) 12.50012
(03/14/13 07:34:00) 12.54736
(03/14/13 07:36:00) 13.05010
(03/14/13 07:38:00) 13.06495
(03/14/13 07:40:00) 13.14084
(03/14/13 07:42:00) 12.92427
(03/14/13 07:44:00) 12.98699
(03/14/13 07:46:00) 12.84172
(03/14/13 07:48:00) 12.87263
(03/14/13 07:50:00) 12.51861
(03/14/13 07:52:00) 12.98763
(03/14/13 07:54:00) 12.31124
(03/14/13 07:56:00) 12.33696
(03/14/13 07:58:00) 12.49630
(03/14/13 08:00:00) 12.40648
(03/14/13 08:02:00) 11.87164
(03/14/13 08:04:00) 12.76058
(03/14/13 08:06:00) 12.50016
(03/14/13 08:08:00) 12.68696
(03/14/13 08:10:00) 12.88447
(03/14/13 08:12:00) 12.33336
(03/14/13 08:14:00) 13.06670
(03/14/13 08:16:00) 13.15070
(03/14/13 08:18:00) 12.82410
(03/14/13 08:20:00) 12.91953
```

outflow2

```
(03/14/13 07:54:00) (03/14/13 07:56:00) (03/14/13 07:58:00) (03/14/13 08:00:00) (03/14/13 08:02:00) (03/14/13 08:04:00) 
           11.51110            11.11878            11.05775            11.11303            10.95417            10.98035
```

Use:

```
> test <- rollapply(inflow, width = 6, by = 1, FUN = cor(inflow, outflow))
Error in cor(inflow, outflow) : incompatible dimensions
```

Comment: I think you need to define what you mean by "correlation" between a single value and multiple values. And if the outflow variable is measured at irregular times, then how do you expect the inflow values to be partitioned.

Comment: I want to correlate the outflow values with the inflow values, as groups of 6.  Sorry, I'm not able to describe this better.  Here's  a text example"

Comment: I guess we need to get concrete: What is the "correlation" of value 3 with the sequence 1:6? Or are you really asking to have the correlation of the aggregated means of the longer vector with the shorter vector?

Comment: ab|              a             a
ab|    cor1      ab|           a
ab|              ab|cor2       ab|
a                ab|           ab|cor3
a                a             ab|

Etc.

Comment: Another way of explaining this… get the correlation between the smaller object (outflow, 6 rows) and the first six rows of the larger object (inflow).  Increment the inflow start position by one, select 6 rows and get correlation with outflow.  Continue comparing inflow to outflow, by six rows, incrementing inflow by one each time, to the end of inflow.   Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: Then I say again, please define "correlation between smaller object and larger object". Apparently you do not mean the signed or unsigned difference between smaller and mean of larger within a window, although that is what I expected you meant. I thought you would accept `cor(rollapply(inflow, 6, mean) , y)` but perhaps you have a different goal?

Comment: The times of the outflow match up to 2 minute intervals that are only present in the middle of you inflow object. Doing a correlation with the `cor(rollapply ) . , mean),y)` might succeed but I think it would be meaningless. You should plot these data together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
rollapply(inflow, 6, cor, y = outflow)
```

This computes

```
value <- c( cor(inflow[1:6], outflow), cor(inflow[2:7], outflow), ...etc... )
ix <- seq(3, length = length(inflow) - 6 + 1)
zoo(value, time(inflow)[ix])
```

Depending on what you want to get out you may need the `align=` argument too.

Comment: I have added a description of the output.

Comment: I don't think that is what is being expected. `outflow[2]` is being measured during the same interval as `inflow[7:12]`. Furthermore when I try using `cor(1:6, 3)` I get a dimension error. (Actually the English description by the OP does not agree with that data.)

Comment: The poster's code and the description by the poster in the comments both seem to describe what I have shown.

Comment: The first element of outflow has an index of `(03/14/13 07:54:00)`. The inflow-object's matching index element is at row 28. The next element in outflow is at `(03/14/13 07:56:00)` and the inflow row that matches that is number 30.

Comment: The times are not relevant.  The desired result is just a matter of calculating `cor` of each successive 6 inflows with the outflow.